# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty {\rm Tr}\left( {\bf A}^{-1} (x \,{\bf A}+{\bf I})^{-1} -\frac{1}{2+x} {\bf I} \right) dx$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I would like to evaluate the following integral.

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty {\rm Tr}\left( {\bf A}^{-1} (x \,{\bf A}+{\bf I})^{-1} -\frac{1}{2+x} {\bf I} \right) dx
\end{align}
where ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a real positive definte matrix and ${\bf I}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$  is an identity.

Unfortunately, my matrix calculus is very weak.  So, any reference where I can look up this would also be great.

For the scalar case, the integral is equal to

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty  \frac{\frac{1}{a}}{ax+1}-\frac{1}{2+x} dx=\log(2)-\log(a).
\end{align}

Thanks.

Comment: You can suppose that the matrix is diagonal.

Comment: @user8268 can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I think it does not converge. Say $A=a$ is a scalar (1x1) matrix. Then this is basically integrating something with a tail that looks like $1/x$. The matrix case is the same thing but with a the scalar being the eigenvalue, and summing over the result for all eigenvalues.

Comment: @NickAlger but $\frac 1{x + 1} - \frac {1}{2 + x}$ has a tail that looks like $\frac 1{x^2}$

Comment: @NickAlger For $n=1$ the integral converges. See  my edit.

Comment: Err, is that scalar integral formula correct for $a\neq 1$? I thought it diverges, and double checking Wolfram alpha agrees. But definite integrals are not my strong suit so I could be wrong

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the scalar integral posted in the question is not correct and it diverges. It disagrees with the results of wolfram alpha, Matlab's symbolic toolbox, and my own by hand calculations. It should be either plus or minus infinity depending on whether $a^2$ is greater or less than 1.

Comment: @NickAlger  Can you add your hand calculation?

Comment: Ok, done. See my answer below.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: but the first term of the integrand is not $(x+1)^{-1}$, it is $(ax + 1)^{-1}$ - there is no cancellation at infinity. Cancellation only occurs when a=1.

Comment: Possibly the second term in the trace $\frac{\rm I}{2+x}$ should actually be $\frac{A^{-2}}{2+x}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $D = P AP^{-1}$ where $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ is diagonal with $\lambda_i > 0$. Then

$$ P (A(xA + I))^{-1} P^{-1} = (P A(xA + I) P^{-1})^{-1} = (x PA^2 P^{-1} + PAP^{-1})^{-1} = (xD^2 + D)^{-1}.$$

Using the invariance of trace under conjugation, we have

$$ \operatorname{Tr} \left( (A(xA + I))^{-1} - \frac{I}{2 + x} \right) = \operatorname{Tr} \left( P \left((A(xA + I))^{-1} - \frac{I}{2 + x} \right) P^{-1} \right) =\\
\operatorname{Tr} \left( (xD^2 + D)^{-1} - \frac{I}{2 + x} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x \lambda_i^2 + \lambda_i} - \frac{1}{2 + x} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x(1 - \lambda_i)^2 + 2 - \lambda_i}{(2 + x) \lambda_i(x\lambda_i + 1)}.$$

This is a rational function whose integral you can calculate explicitly.

Comment: +1, but do you really need diagonalisation? The trace of a matrix is the sum of all eigenvalues...

Comment: In fact, OP has already calculated 
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\frac 1{\lambda_i}}{\lambda_i x + 1} - \frac1{2+x} \right)dx = \log(2/\lambda_i)
$$

Comment: @user1551 well, we would need some kind of spectral mapping theorem for rational functions, then.  It's fine to reference such a fact, but it's unlikely that OP knows about it off the cuff.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Fair enough. It doesn't hurt anyway to diagonalise $A$.

Comment: @user1551: One should know at least that $A$ is diagonalizable to argue that rational expressions in $A$ don't effect the multiplicity of the eigenvalues. But you definitely don't need orthogonal diagonalization.

Comment: I was too quick to comment on it. You are right about the multiplicities.

Comment: But it still diverges at $\infty$. The OP's calculation in the scalar case is wrong.

Comment: @Nick: Like the joke about mathematicians goes, I didn't solve the whole problem, only reduced it to a problem that can be solved algorithmically.

Answer (score 2):

As requested in the comments, here is a by-hand evaluation of the scalar integral.

The indefinite integral of the scalar integrand is:
$$I(x) := \int \left(\frac{\frac{1}{a}}{ax+1} - \frac{1}{2+x}\right)dx = \frac{\log(ax+1)}{a^2} - \log(x+2) + C.$$

The definite integral is:
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1/a}{ax+1} - \frac{1}{2+x}\right)dx = I(\infty)-I(0).$$
Now $I(0) = -\log(2) + C$. To compute $I(\infty)$, we use the rules of logarithms to further combine terms:
$$\frac{\log(ax+1)}{a^2} - \log(x+2) = \log\left(\frac{(ax+1)^{1/a^2}}{x+2}\right).$$
Asymptotically the numerator within the logatirhm acts as $x^{1/a^2}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, and the denominator acts as $x$ in the same limit. So the ratio within the logarithm approaches zero if $1/a^2 < 1$ and infinity if $1/a^2 > 1$. Outside the logarithm this corresponds to values for $I(\infty)$ of $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, respectively.

Hence
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1/a}{ax+1} - \frac{1}{2+x}\right)dx = \begin{cases}
-\infty, & \quad a > 1 \\
+\infty, & \quad a < 1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Well spotted.  I suspect that OP meant to have $\frac {a}{ax + 1}$, which would fix the convergence issue.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That would make sense. I see matrices like $A(A+\omega I)^{-1}$ all the time in different contexts, but I don't know if I have ever naturally come across a matrix like $A^{-1}(A+\omega I)^{-1}$.